# Algebra struggles: 2 problems in 1

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I'm struggling with some concepts in my algebra class. I've chosen these two completely unrelated examples that demonstrate my struggling topics (characteristics and function rings) the two are the following:

$1$) Let $X$ be a set, and let $S$ be a ring. Give a proof that the left distributive law holds for $(S^X, +, *)$.

$2$) Suppose $Y^3 = Y$ for each element $Y$ of a unital ring $R$. Show that $R$ has a finite characteristic d that is a divisor of $6$.

Any example solutions for these proofs would be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: i don't understand these topics in parenthesis. ive tried nothing as i don't know where to start

Comment: anybody out there?

Comment: What *precisely* don't you understand about the characteristic of a ring, and about function rings?  Do you know the definitions? The more details you give the greater the possibility that the answers will apply to your specific difficulties. If you make answerers *guess* such, then they may waste time addressing things that don't apply to your situation. Better to be specific.

Comment: I don't understand what the structure in 1) means
and i don't understand how to figure out patterns of characteristics or what characteristics are.

Comment: It would help if you answered my prior question. Do you know what a function ring is, in particular the function ring $S^X$? Do you know the definition of the characteristic of a ring?

Comment: I now understand 1) from the answer given by pjs36. However, I don't understand the characteristics questions because i'm struggling to define characteristics or how to find patterns in it.

Comment: What is your definition of the characteristic of a ring?

Comment: I'm not sure. thats my struggle. I've never heard the term before related to rings.

Comment: The source of the problems did not define the terms? Or did you miss some lectures?

Comment: My teacher doesn't touch every topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll start with 1) for now since I haven't quite figured 2) out. If nobody else is interested, I'll come back and edit this in later.

For 1), it helps to unpack the definition of $S^X$. I assume that $S^X$ is the set of functions from a set $X$ to $S$; that is,
$$
S^X := \{f: X \to S \}
$$
and that this naturally inherits its ring structure from that of $S$. Specifically, given functions $f, g, h \in S^X$, it only makes sense to *define*

$$
(f+g)(x) := f(x)+g(x),
$$ and
$$
(f\cdot g)(x) := f(x)\cdot g(x).
$$

Now, what would left-distributivity even mean in this context? Basically, we have to verify
$$
\big(h\cdot (f+g)\big)(x) = (h\cdot f)(x) + (h \cdot g)(x) = \big( (h \cdot f)+(h \cdot g) \big)(x). 
$$
I think if you just figure out how to interpret the left hand side, you'll see it's really just symbol pushing, and that distributivity of $(S^X, +, \cdot)$ inherits distributivity from $S$ in a very straightforward way.

Comment: Thank you! so this problem is basically using the distributive law within our defined context so it will work for verification line?